# asp.net new Bitmap of file in relative path of ASP.NET Solution and not fully qualified file system?

Tags: asp.net, azure, bitmap, drawing, cloud-storage

Is it possible to reference a new bitmap pointing to file in the .NET solution without giving it a fully qualified file system location? Trying to do this to run in Azure without having to set up cloud storage.

This code fails to resolve a.jpg... I tried \a.jpg, ~\a.jpg, etc.  Suspect NOT but asking just in case I'm missing something here.

```
    context.Response.Clear();
    //Bitmap bitMapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((@"P:\somedirectory\a.jpg"));
    Bitmap bitMapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((@"a.jpg"));
    Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
```

UPDATE: also tried

```
Bitmap bitMapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("a.jpg"));
```

Comment: If it's a web app, have you tried Server.MapPath?

Comment: yes. this does not work: parameter is invalid.. Bitmap bitMapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("a.jpg"));  tried /a.jpg and ~/a.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I use this in Azure with MVC 4

```
string strAttachFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/images/GM.gif");
```

Comment: sorry for delay. going to test this.